# Ordering cells by their distance from center cell(s)

Tags: python, matrix, optimization

I had someone ask me, what at that time seemed an innocent enough question:

How do we ordering cells in a 2D array by their distance from predefined/precomputed center cell(s).

Here is a table showing how far the particular cell is from predefined center cells ( they have values of 0 in them ). A value of n means it's n cells away from the center:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 4  | 4  | 3  | 3  | 3  | 3  | 4  | 4  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 4  | 3  | 2  | 2  | 2  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 3  | 2  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 3  | 2  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 3  | 2  | 1  | 0  | 0  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 3  | 2  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 1  | 2  | 3  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 4  | 3  | 2  | 2  | 2  | 2  | 3  | 4  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
| 4  | 4  | 3  | 3  | 3  | 3  | 4  | 4  |
+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+----+
```

I solved the problem by computing the straight line distance between ( x1, y1 ) and ( x2, y2 ) in an Euclidean space and sorting them using the old school "Decorate-Sort-Undecorate" method.

This is what I ended up with:

```
import math
boardMaxRow = 8
boardMaxCol = 8
thatAbsurdLargeValue = ( 1 + boardMaxRow + boardMaxCol )
centerCells = ( ( 3, 3 ), ( 3, 4 ), ( 4, 3 ), ( 4, 4 ) )
cellsOrderedFromTheCenter = {}

for row in xrange( boardMaxRow ):
    for col in xrange( boardMaxCol ):
        minDistanceFromCenter = thatAbsurdLargeValue
        for ( centerX, centerY ) in centerCells:
            # straight line distance between ( x1, y1 ) and ( x2, y2 ) in an Euclidean space
            distanceFromCenter = int( 0.5 + math.sqrt( ( row - centerX ) ** 2 + ( col - centerY ) ** 2 ) )
            minDistanceFromCenter = min( minDistanceFromCenter, distanceFromCenter )
        cellsOrderedFromTheCenter[ ( row, col ) ] = minDistanceFromCenter

board = [ keyValue for keyValue in cellsOrderedFromTheCenter.items() ]

import operator

# sort the board in ascending order of distance from the center
board.sort( key = operator.itemgetter( 1 ) )
boardWithCellsOrderedFromTheCenter = [ key for ( key , Value ) in board ]
print boardWithCellsOrderedFromTheCenter
```

The output:

```
[(3, 3), (4, 4), (4, 3), (3, 4), (5, 4), (2, 5), (2, 2), (5, 3), (3, 2), (4, 5), (5, 5), (2, 3), (4, 2), (3, 5), (5, 2), (2, 4), (1, 3), (6, 4), (5, 6), (2, 6), (5, 1), (1, 2), (6, 3), (1, 5), (3, 6), (4, 1), (1, 4), (2, 1), (6, 5), (4, 6), (3, 1), (6, 2), (7, 3), (4, 7), (3, 0), (1, 6), (3, 7), (0, 3), (7, 2), (4, 0), (2, 0), (5, 7), (1, 1), (2, 7), (6, 6), (5, 0), (0, 4), (7, 5), (6, 1), (0, 2), (7, 4), (0, 5), (0, 7), (6, 7), (7, 6), (7, 7), (0, 0), (7, 1), (6, 0), (1, 0), (0, 1), (7, 0), (0, 6), (1, 7)]
```

I am amazed at how much code I got in there, for such a trivial problem.

My question is : can I make it faster and/or shorter ( use less temporaries/function calls )?

Comment: Seems you are computing the diagonals in two different ways. The succession 0,1,3,4 in the diagonals? Sure?

Comment: @belisarius : Do you disagree with the values in the matrix above?

Comment: Just seemed weird that the diagonals do not increase in steps of 1.

Comment: @belisarius : Yes, but because there is more than one center cell. I am open to opposing views and what it should have been.

Comment: Don't care. Your distance function has a symmetry, that's all. I first thought you was trying to get something with translational symmetry, but that was just my understanding as the other respondents did wonderfully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it shorter (and using a slightly different metric):

```
>>> rows, cols, centerx, centery = 6, 6, 2.5, 2.5
>>> [p[1:] for p in sorted((((x - centerx) ** 2 + (y - centery) ** 2, x, y)
...                         for x in xrange(rows) for y in xrange(cols)))]
[(2, 2), (2, 3), (3, 2), (3, 3), (1, 2), (1, 3), 
 (2, 1), (2, 4), (3, 1), (3, 4), (4, 2), (4, 3), 
 (1, 1), (1, 4), (4, 1), (4, 4), (0, 2), (0, 3),
 (2, 0), (2, 5), (3, 0), (3, 5), (5, 2), (5, 3), 
 (0, 1), (0, 4), (1, 0), (1, 5), (4, 0), (4, 5),
 (5, 1), (5, 4), (0, 0), (0, 5), (5, 0), (5, 5)]
```

To make it faster:

- Don't take square roots (as in my code above): sorting by the square of the distance is just as good as sorting by the distance, and taking square roots is <del>relatively slow</del> unnecessary.
- Exploit the 8-way symmetry: sort one octant and copy it out 8 times.

---

In the comments, PoorLuzer asks, "I also did not understand why you init centerx, centery = 2.5, 2.5." I hope this figure makes it clear:

[image: the centre of a 6x6 grid with coordinates running from 0 to 5 on each axis is at 2.5,2.5]

PoorLuzer also wonders how come our metrics differ, given that we are both using the Euclidean distance formula. Well, my metric takes the distance from the centre of each square to the centre of the whole grid. For example, for these 8 cells the distance from the centre is √2.5 = about 1.58:

[image: distance to centre for eight cells is sqrt(2.5)]

Whereas PoorLuzer is taking the Euclidean distance to the closest of the four centre squares (and rounding it to an integer). For the same 8 cells PoorLuzer assigns a distance of 1:

[image: distance for same eight cells is 1 in PoorLuzer's metric]

Comment: Taking a square root isn't relatively slow compared to the cost of being in a VM.  It'll be faster, but probably only a little, and probably mostly just due to executing a couple fewer bytecode ops.

Comment: Also, note that he's rounding the distance before using it (what?), which means that you do need to take the sqrt, since the results are different.

Comment: Hence my "slightly different metric". I don't think his metric makes any sense, so I didn't feel obliged to copy it.

Comment: I'd suggest that it's just premature optimization, and not a good habit: unless the speed matters, you're better off dealing with real distances, and not leaving out the sqrt unless you have a reason to.  It'll save confusion later when, for example, you decide to use the distance for something else, or examine the value in a debugger.

Comment: Leaving out the `sqrt` when sorting by a euclidean distance is completely mathematically valid since `for all x,y: x < y -> x**2 < y**2` -- so the sort order will never change.

Comment: @Glenn: I disagree. The length squared of a vector is a useful property to compute for many common tests (is vector non-zero? which vector is longer? are vectors perpendicular? is point in circle? etc), and it is a waste to compute the square root in these cases when you didn't have to. Theoretical confusion can be handled by appropriate naming of functions and values.

Comment: The reason why I had done the sqrt was because this was for a school kid and I wanted to be pedantic. It's a valid optimization though, considering the current use-case. In that case I also do not need the round()!

Comment: Oh - the reason why I used the metric is to generate a matrix that looks like the one in the question. Is there a better metric to obtain how far a call is from the center cell(s)?

Comment: There's the [Euclidean metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_distance) — the straight-line distance, and there's the [Manhattan metric](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) — sum of distance along and distance up. I'm afraid that yours is neither.

Comment: @Gareth : From that WP entry, I am using the very same expression that it suggests under "In the Euclidean plane, if p =". Hence, is it not an Euclidean metric? I also did not understand why you init centerx, centery = 2.5, 2.5. Your observation about symmetry was excellent!

Comment: Excellent answer! How did you make those diagrams?

Answer (score 1):

Shorter is easy:

```
coordinates = [(x,y) for y in range(boardMaxRow) 
                     for x in range(boardMaxCol)]

def dist(A,B):
    a,b = A
    c,d = B
    # real euklidian distance without rounding
    return (a-c)**2+(b-d)**2 

print list(sorted(coordinates, 
    key=lambda x: min(dist(x,c) for c in centerCells)))
```

Comment: The distance function you're using is different.  He's using `round(Math.sqrt(Math.pow(a-b, 2) + Math.pow(b-d, 2)))` for some reason.

Comment: The reason why I had done the sqrt was because this was for a school kid and I wanted to be pedantic. It's a valid optimization though, considering the current use-case. In that case I also do not need the round()!

Comment: Oh - the reason why I used the metric is to generate a matrix that looks like the one in the question. Is there a better metric to obtain how far a call is from the center cell(s)?